# How do I make Sundown render blockquotes (lines that start with ">")

Tags: html, objective-c, c, markdown, sundown

For whatever reason, Sundown (more specifically [Snudown](https://github.com/reddit/snudown), a fork of it) doesn't seem to output lines like:

```
> some text
```

As blockquotes in HTML, like it should, as it's valid Markdown. I know there are extensions in Sundown that allow certain features, but I cannot find one for quotes.

Here's the code I'm using (it's in Objective-C, but for the most part it's C):

```
struct sd_callbacks callbacks;
struct html_renderopt options;
const char *rawMarkdown = [markdownString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
struct buf *inputBuffer = bufnew(strlen(rawMarkdown));
bufputs(inputBuffer, rawMarkdown);

// Parse the Markdown
struct buf *outputBuffer = bufnew(64);
sdhtml_renderer(&callbacks, &options, 0);
unsigned int extensions = MKDEXT_NO_INTRA_EMPHASIS|MKDEXT_TABLES|MKDEXT_FENCED_CODE|MKDEXT_AUTOLINK|MKDEXT_STRIKETHROUGH|MKDEXT_SUPERSCRIPT|MKDEXT_LAX_SPACING;
struct sd_markdown *markdown = sd_markdown_new(extensions, 16, 4, &callbacks, &options);
sd_markdown_render(outputBuffer, inputBuffer->data, inputBuffer->size, markdown);
sd_markdown_free(markdown);

NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithCString:bufcstr(outputBuffer) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

bufrelease(inputBuffer);
bufrelease(outputBuffer);

NSLog(@"%@", HTML);
```

If a sample project would be helpful to show the issue, please just say so.

Comment: Blockquotes are on by default in Sundown (I'm not sure you can even disable them). Could you post the whole document you're working with (or a large excerpt at least)? I did find this [bug report](https://github.com/vmg/sundown/issues/92) that says Sundown requires blockquotes to be preceded by a blank line. Have you considered using a different Markdown library? Sundown is [basically abandoned](https://github.com/vmg/sundown/issues/155).

Comment: @Jordan Unfortunately not, I'm using a fork of Sundown that Reddit uses called [Snudown](https://github.com/reddit/snudown). I'll post the block of code I'm using, it's in Objective-C but mostly comprised of C code. I basically get the HTML from the Markdown, then print it out, but it still includes the > character and no blockquotes are applied.

Comment: I don't know what sundown is, but it could be stripping ">" characters for html security or clean up reasons. Is it possible you can try replacing the ">" characters in your content with the "&gt;" entity?

Comment: have you created a issue in the github project?

Comment: Some of the quoted text and its surroundings would be helpful. Have you made sure that each line that you expect to be quoted starts with a `>` followed by a space?

Comment: As per the github bug mentioned by @Jordan which is still open, have you tried adding a blank space before block quote ?

Comment: Did you check whether in input text  string the `blockquote` is coming as `>`or `&gt;`? May be that's why markdown not giving back block quote

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, '<' and '>' cannot be used directly,

Use an html entity:

`&gt;` to display >

`&lt;` to display <

Click edit to view it, the entity codes were used instead of '>' and '<'.